# How to retrieve MyTitle from a tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox

On page 99 of the tcolorbox 3.80 manual, there is an example, given a new `tcolorbox`, of how to retrieve the *name* of the tcolorbox,  i.e "BlueBox", (`\nameCref{myreference}`), the *counter number* of the particular tcolorbox, i.e, "0.0.1" (`\labelcref{myreference`}), and the *page number*, i.e. "99" in the manual (`\labelcpageref{myreference}`).

What I cannot figure out is how to retrieve the *title* of the particular tcolorbox, i.e. "My title".

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtcolorbox[%
auto counter,%
number within=section,%
crefname={bluebox}{blueboxes}%
]% 
{%
mybluebox%
}%
[2][]%
{%
colback=blue!5!white,%
colframe=blue!75!black,%
fonttitle=\bfseries,%
title=Bluebox \thetcbcounter: #2,#1%
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{mybluebox}[label={myreference}]{My title}
This is an example.
\end{mybluebox}

\nameCref{myreference}

\labelcref{myreference}

\labelcpageref{myreference}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a `nameref` attribute to the `tcolorbox` definition. This attribute can be accessed using the label name with the `\nameref` command (which requires loading the `nameref` package).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{nameref}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section,crefname={bluebox}{blueboxes}]{mybluebox}[2][]%
{colback=blue!5!white,colframe=blue!75!black,fonttitle=\bfseries,%
title=Bluebox \thetcbcounter: #2,%
nameref=#2,%
#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybluebox}[label={myreference}]{My title}
This is an example.
\end{mybluebox}

\nameCref{myreference}

\labelcref{myreference}

\labelcpageref{myreference}

Title: \nameref{myreference}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]